# Get hash keys or type of value in a hash

Tags: sorbet

Coming from `flowtype`, I'm used to having things like `$Keys<obj>` to say 'the union of all the keys in `obj`'. Also, `$PropertyType<obj, 'key'>` to get the type of the value of `obj[key]`.

I'm looking for something similar in Sorbet so I can make better use of generics.

Ideally I want the `key` param to be `T.any(<keys in the hash>)` and the return value to be `typeof hash[:key]`

This is what I'd like to happen:

```rb
# my_rbi.rbi

class SomeClass

  Elem = type_member

  sig { params(key: Keys[Elem]).returns(PropertyType<Elem, key>) }
  def [](key); end

end

# somewhere else

sig { returns(SomeClass[{ my_key: String }]) } # add the hash as a generic
def context
  # return the context
end

context[:my_key] # works, is a String!
context[:not_my_key] # fails
```

Is any of this possible? what are my options here?

Context:

My use case is types for `graphql-ruby`, in particular `GraphQL::Query::Context`. It essentially delegates `[]` to an internal hash, which I know the shape of. I'd like to pass a generic to `GraphQL::Query::Context`, like `GraphQL::Query::Context[{ my_key: String }]`. Then, in the `def []` signature, I'd like to say what the available options for `key` are based on the generic hash.

Comment: I don't use `graphql-ruby` so I can't say it will work. But the closest you probably can find is function `type_parameter`. It can tie the given type of `key` with the return type. See example in sorbet.try#GenericMethod

Comment: @hdoan can you check my edit please? i've removed the references to `graphql-ruby` and added some details to the post to more accurately describe what i'm looking for.

Comment: It seems fairly complex. I might be wrong but sorbet doesn't support this level of generic yet. Wait until they have some utility method on type like $Key and $Value in `flow` :-(

Comment: Check out the documentation on Shape: https://sorbet.org/docs/shapes